# How to correctly use generics in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, axios

I get stuck with generics . How can I correctly use generics in my case:

```
export interface Location {
  id: number;
  address: {
    houseNumber: string;
  };
}
export const getEuropeLocations = async (
  apiKey: string
) => {
  let response = await axios.get<Location>({ 
    method: "get",
    url: `${apiBaseUrl}europe/`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
    },
  });
  return response.data;
};
```

have error with types :
"{  "message": "Argument of type '{ method: string; url: string; headers: { Authorization: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.",

}"

Comment: You say you're stuck, but what is the problem?  Does your question depend on `axios`? If so, please tag it as such, if not, consider removing the example code's dependence on it.  The goal here is for you to give us a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](//tsplay.dev/mbGkoW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values (like `axios` or `apiBaseUrl`).

Comment: @jcalz Ditto. OP, I'll be happy to rescind my downvote once you've described your problem, clarified whether your question depends on axios, and provided a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios has typings for this. It lets you specify a generic type for the axios functions so that `result.data` will have that generic type.

For example, you can do this:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getEuropeLocations = async (
  apiKey: string
) => {
  let response = await axios.get<Location>(`${apiBaseUrl}europe/`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
    },
  });
  return response.data;
};
```

If you want to make the entire function generic, you can do this:

```
export const getEuropeLocations = async <T>(
  apiKey: string
) => {
  let response = await axios.get<T>(`${apiBaseUrl}europe/`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
    },
  });
  return response.data;
};
```

Comment: but in that way, it would be an error: "Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments."

Comment: @Puzzle234 How are you importing axios? Are you doing something like `import axios from "axios";`? Can you show this line?

Comment: const axios = require("axios"); what the difference ?

Comment: @Puzzle234 are you calling a specific function like `get`? For example `axios.get<Location>( ... )`

Comment: question updated

Comment: @Puzzle234 Woops, try it like this: `axios.get<Location>(\`${apiBaseUrl}europe/\`, { .... })` where `...` is that object. See my updated answer